# Где бы найти диаграмму классов .NET Framework?

Tags: .net

Мой начальник хочет, чтобы наше ядро документооборота было разбито на пространства имён по тем же принципам, что и .NET Framework. Для этого мне нужно найти диаграмму классов .NET Framework и описать концептуальную модель именования пространств имён.

Comment: прошло три года, как была решена задача?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.NET Framework 3.5 Common Namespaces and Types Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19341)

Comment: [NET Framework 3.5 Common Namespaces and Types Poster](http://4put.ru/pictures/max/235/724318.jpg)